# With "npm list" - is there a way to use wildcard / regex?

Tags: npm

I couldn't find a way to do e.g.:

```
npm list -g *json*
```

(Been trying `npm list -g | sls json` via PowerShell, but PowerShell seems to have difficulties with it as it hags for few min. after that command...)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no parameter on `npm ls` that enable that natively which would be a great addition.

The only solution I found so far that may help you is to use grep.

i.e.:

```
npm list -g | grep json
```

That will show only lines matching whatever you pass to grep, but that won't show the structure of dependencies correctly and then does not help to find who depends on a specific instance of that dependency, but is a start.